# find length of curve of intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves, parametric

I have come to a dead end on a problem and I need someone to tell me either if I did it correctly, or how to fix it if I did not.  This is Stewart Calculus 7th edition, problem 13.3.12.

Here is the problem definition:
"Find, correct to four decimal places, the length of the curve of intersection of the cylinder $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and the plane $x + y + z = 2$."

The answer I got is 13.5191, but I am asking for people here to review this because I reached a seemingly unsolvable integral and I had to resort to using my calculator.

Here is my work: $$x^2 +(1/4)y^2 = 1$$

$$\begin{align*}x &= \cos t \\
y &= 2 \sin t  \\
z &= 2 - \cos t - 2\sin t
\end{align*}$$ for $ 0 \le t \le 2\pi $.
$$ r'(t) = (-\sin t, 2\cos t, (\sin t - 2 \cos t)) $$

Then $$  L = \int_a^b |r'(t)| dt $$

I then squared each component of $r'(t)$, summed the components, and took the square root to define the integral. I simplified twice to get:
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2\sin^2 t + 8\cos^2 t - 4\sin t \cos t} dt $$

For the interval 0 to $2\pi$, the calculator gives 13.51908915

Can anyone show me the solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  The integral can be simplified a bit to
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{3 \cos(2t) - 2 \sin(2t) +  5}\ dt  = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\sqrt{13} \cos(s) + 5}\ ds$$
This can be expressed in terms of elliptic integral or hypergeometric functions, e.g. it is
$2\;\pi \sqrt{5} \;{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(-1/4,1/4;\,1;\,{ {13}/{25}})}$, but I doubt that there is an elementary
 solution.

The fact that Stewart asks for an answer "to four decimal places" indicates that you are not expected to find an exact expression.

Comment: Thank you for answering this.