# Universal substitution or Feynman trick to solve this integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, parametric

I started with an integral $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2[\sin^2(t) + 16\cos^2(t) - 4\sin(t)\cos(t)]} \,dt $

And I simplified it to $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{17 + 15\cos(2t) - 4\sin(2t)} \, dt$

My question: I know this can be simplified with some sort of substitution that cancels the $\sin$ and $\cos$ with a $u$-sub, but I do not know how. I saw it online, with no explanation (see the first answer: [find length of curve of intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200010/find-length-of-curve-of-intersection)).

I think this has an exact elementary solution, if you use $\tan\left(\frac x2\right)$ substitution and possibly Feynman's trick if necessary.

Comment: There, it should have been $...-2\sin2t$ not $...-4\sin2t$.

Comment: @BobDobbs No, I numerically verified their simplification up to at least 9 digits. The OP should be correct.

Comment: OPs are always right @Accelerator

Comment: Ahhh.... Oh my bad.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos2t-2\sin2t}\,dt&\overset{2t=x}{=}\frac12\int_0^{4\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos x-2\sin x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos x-2\sin x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}\cos(x+\alpha)}\,dx\\
&=\int_\alpha^{2\pi+\alpha}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}\cos x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}\cos x}\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}\cos x}\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}-2\sqrt{229}\sin^2(\frac x2)}\,dx\,\, (\text{By $\cos x=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$})\\
&\overset{x\rightarrow 2x}{=}4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}-2\sqrt{229}\sin^2x}\,dx\\
&=4\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{2\sqrt{229}}{17+\sqrt{229}}\sin^2x}\,dx\\
&=4\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{17\sqrt{229}-229}{30}\sin^2x}\,dx\\
&=4\sqrt{17+\sqrt{229}}E\left(\sqrt{\frac{17\sqrt{229}-229}{30}}\right)
\end{align}$
In agreement with Wolfram Alpha. [Here, WA uses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_0%5E%282pi%29sqrt%2817%2B15cosx-2sinx%29dx) $m=\frac{17\sqrt{229}-229}{30}$ but I used $k=\sqrt m$ as the variable of the function $E$.

Comment: Your solution's first step is $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos2t-2\sin2t}dt$ when it should be $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos2t-4\sin2t}dt$.

Comment: But, method is correct. And they say don't delete the answers it is not ethic. What should I do?

Comment: You can start with the integral I pointed out and do the same methods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this integral has an elementary closed form, but there is a way to express it in terms of a [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos2x-4\sin2x}dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos x-4\sin x}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17+15\cos x-4\sin x}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17-\sqrt{241}\sin\left(x-\arctan\left(\frac{15}{4}\right)\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{-\arctan\left(\frac{15}{4}\right)}^{2\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{15}{4}\right)}\sqrt{17-\sqrt{241}\sin x}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17-\sqrt{241}\sin x}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{17-\sqrt{241}\cos x}dx \\
&= \sqrt{17}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{241}}{17}\cos x}dx \\
&= 4\sqrt{17-\sqrt{241}} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{241}}{\sqrt{241}-17}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where in the last line, we use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938271/evaluating-a-trigonometric-integral-with-square-root/3938279#3938279).

Comment: I thought there is a singularity here.

Comment: What singularity? @BobDobbs